# Can I still can apply for R-ATP 1000 hour, if I get my multi engine add on under part 61?

Tags: faa-regulations, faa, pilot-certification

I have completed my private, instrument rating, and commercial under part 141. Can I still able apply for R-ATP 1000 hours, if I get my multi-engine add-on under part 61?